# Swift watch. Sending data from one view controller to another

Tags: ios, swift, instance, watchkit

I am trying to send an instance of Data class object from my ViewController to DataViewControllerSwift.

ViewController

```
var data : Data = Data()

data = dataList?.objectAtIndex(rowIndex) as Data
var dataViewController : DataViewControllerSwift?

dataViewController!.data = data
self.pushControllerWithName("DataaaViewControllerSwift", context: nil)
```

DataViewControllerSwift

```
 class DataViewControllerSwift: WKInterfaceController {
 var data : Data! = Data()
 }
```

However data instance is nil in my DataViewControllerSwift. I am little confuse and don't know why this is happening.

I tired this

```
 var dataViewController : DataViewControllerSwift? = DataViewControllerSwift()
```

however I only got an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats not really a good way to pass data between controllers in WatchKit.

First, in your `ViewController`, you should do

```
var data = dataList?.objectAtIndex(rowIndex) as Data
self.pushControllerWithName("DataViewControllerSwift", context: data)
```

So that you can pass the data from your `ViewController` to `DataViewController` via `context`

Second, in your `DataViewController`'s `override func awakeWithContext(context: AnyObject?)` method, you can do the following to get the data passed from `ViewController`:

```
if let theData = context as? Data {
   self.data = theData
}
```

Comment: I had a brain fart, the other App I've worked on has the view controllers in AppDelelgate. So I could push data like the way I have up in my example because the AppDelegate is a singleton that keeps the view controllers alive.